# Type casting a part of a Pandas dataframe (multiple columns) and assigning back does not preserve the dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I'm relatively new to Pandas so this may be trivial. As this *should* be a common problem I already searched for similar problems to this but couldn't find anything (there are some resembling this but they pertain to columns with mixed dtypes). Sorry if this is a duplicate, kind TIA for pointers.

Problem: A part of a dataframe (subset of columns and/or rows) need to be converted from "object" to e.g. a numerical type (say, `float`).  While casting using `astype()` for those row/columns works, assigning back to the original (sub)dataframe using `iloc` indexing does revert to the original dtype.

Concrete example (simplified):

````
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

# Numbers are deliberately added as strings -- to be converted later

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Olivia','Dean','Alex','Jon','Tom','Jane','Kate'],
...            'age': ['32','23','45','35','20','28','55'],
...            'height':['1.65', '1.75','1.85','1.91','1.75','1.7','1.65']})

>>> df
     name age height
0  Olivia  32   1.65
1    Dean  23   1.75
2    Alex  45   1.85
3     Jon  35   1.91
4     Tom  20   1.75
5    Jane  28    1.7
6    Kate  55   1.65
```


>>> df.dtypes
name      object
age       object
height    object
dtype: object

>>> # Convert second and third column to `float`, assign it back to the original dataframe 

>>> df.iloc[:,1:]  = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(float)

>>> df
     name   age height
0  Olivia  32.0   1.65
1    Dean  23.0   1.75
2    Alex  45.0   1.85
3     Jon  35.0   1.91
4     Tom  20.0   1.75
5    Jane  28.0    1.7
6    Kate  55.0   1.65
>>> df.dtypes
name      object
age       object
height    object

# However, the conversion by itself has the expected result

>>> df_sub  = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(float)

>>> df_sub
    age  height
0  32.0    1.65
1  23.0    1.75
2  45.0    1.85
3  35.0    1.91
4  20.0    1.75
5  28.0    1.70
6  55.0    1.65
>>> df_sub.dtypes
age       float64
height    float64

# Strangely, if instead of `iloc` I use an index for a subset of column, I get the expected result  

>>> cols_idx =  df.columns.drop('name')

>>> df[cols_idx] = df[cols_idx].astype(float)

>>> df.dtypes
name       object
age       float64
height    float64
dtype: object
````

Can someone please explain the difference / why using `iloc` does NOT give me the result I want ?  Also, what is the recommended way to do this for larger dataframes (several hundred rows / columns) ?

Kind TIA,

/Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, by performing the `iloc[:,1:]` reassignemnt, you are essentially performing:

```
df.iloc.__setitem__((i, slice(None)), value)
```

In which case you are setting the new values within the corresponding index locations for the dataframe you are overwriting, but not modifying the pre-existing properties of the dataframe, or columns you are affecting. Nowhere, are you actually overwriting the `dtypes` of the existing column of the dataframe you are working on.

In the other two examples:

```
df_sub  = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(float)
```

You are creating a new variable `df_sub` which equals to the output of `df.iloc[:,1:].astype(float)`, of course being `dtype == float`

In this other example:

```
df[cols_idx] = df[cols_idx].astype(float)
```

You are indeed reassigning a dataframe with it's new `dtypes`, not only the values (as in the column properties get also re-assigned).

Comment: First, kind thanks for the answer.

The key take-away from this is that I cannot use `iloc` indexing to change the underlying type of a row / column / cell -- only the value. 

Two follow-up questions if I may 

1/ I don't quite understand why the 2nd option works -- assigning to a sub-set of columns in the _original_ dataframe ?

2/ Most importantly: How do I change the type subset of rows AND columns, or a single cell ? I can do that with column indexes (above) -- and possibly with (row) indexes (haven't tried yet) -- but I can't think of a way to combine them. 

Kind TIA again

Comment: The other way I can think of doing it is construct a new dataframe with the same shape, and then copy from the old one to new one with the correct types -- but that seems really tedious / awkward....